# Schedule job executes twice on cluster

Tags: java, tomcat, cluster-computing, scheduler

We are using Cron4j java scheduler for scheduling jobs which execute every night. Now, when this same web application is deployed(Tomcat) on cluster(2 nodes) at the client's site the jobs run twice. Is there any way to avoid this problem?

Comment: Have you considered running your scheduler standalone and not part of the Tomcat cluster?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the only way of doing this would be to use some external shared state, like in a database for example, to provide some locking.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Shedlock](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock) library, it's very simple

```
@Scheduled(...)
@SchedulerLock(name = "scheduledTaskName")
public void scheduledTask() {

}
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the ways to solve it would be to make your webapp to accept a parameter, e.g. `runCronjobs`. You could put relevant entry in `web.xml` or in some other configuration file.

So one webapp would have this value set to `true` and other deployments would have it set to `false`.